# How to remove matching item from nested list?

Tags: python, string, list, nested-lists

I have a list with lists and I would like remove a wildcard matching item from each list if present, otherwise return it as it is.

Example

```
nested_list = [["abc","fds","gfssdf"],["dfsdf","cds","dvc"],["dsaf","abcvs","ewq"],...]
```

What I tried to do is:

```
for x in nested_list :
    for y in x:
        if re.search('abc.+', y) in x:
            nested_list.remove(x)
```

However it returns the same list, without any changes

My desirable output would be:

```
nested_list = [["fds","gfssdf"],["dfsdf","cds","dvc"],["dsaf","ewq"],...]
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this with a nested 2D list comprehension:

```py
nested_list = [["abc","fds","gfssdf"],["dfsdf","cds","dvc"],["dsaf","abcvs","ewq"]]
output = [[y for y in x if not re.search(r'^abc', y)] for x in nested_list]
print(output)  # [['fds', 'gfssdf'], ['dfsdf', 'cds', 'dvc'], ['dsaf', 'ewq']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71845166/5625547) are providing a nice solution, but I wanted to answer OP's original question for learning purposes

---

There are some mistakes in your code, I'll adress them one by one:

1. `if re.search('abc.+', y) in x:`
   `re.search` returns `None` if it's not found, so you can remove the `in x`
2. The `+` in `abc.+` searched for 1 or more, since you want to match `abc`, change the `+` to a `?` to match 0 or more
3. If you'd remove all the elements from an deeper list, you'll end op with a empty list, so lets add a check for that and remove the empty list:

   ```py
   if not x:
       nested_list.remove(x)
   ```

---

Applying those fixes gives us:

```py
import re

nested_list = [["abc","fds","gfssdf"],["dfsdf","cds","dvc"],["dsaf","abcvs","ewq"], ["abc"]]

for x in nested_list :
    for y in x:
        if re.search('abc.?', y):
            x.remove(y)
            if not x:
                nested_list.remove(x)

print(nested_list)
```

Witch gives the expected output:

```
[['fds', 'gfssdf'], ['dfsdf', 'cds', 'dvc'], ['dsaf', 'ewq']]
```

As you can test [in this online demo](https://tio.run/##VY7NCsMgEITvPsXiJREkl94KpQ8SQrH@NEKjqUqqT2@1IdTOQdxvnFnXFGZrTjnrZbUugJMIGemDFLen9gEuMI6Y3TmmWAlfzofyXig80RELVW8U868hNr5Tzyosma1i@X4VDHvJNCGkrIMI2kC75oygqFqpWnGfq7Qqfxq8ZI7PfVdKhmtHIZHfi6o4OLnYTfaJ/PGSNja0fYea7Uc2EoRWp03oG5Pk/AE).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using `startswith` instead of `re`:

```
>>> [[y for y in x if not y.startswith("abc")] for x in nested_list]
[['fds', 'gfssdf'], ['dfsdf', 'cds', 'dvc'], ['dsaf', 'ewq']]
```